# button click to pass list item id to load another list in android

Tags: android, json

I'm new in android. i developed a simple program with using web back end.It is City to place display. Here My app structure, Cities list --> City info --> Places list -->Place info. When i click city list one item then view clicked item city id related city info, if click places button in city info that view current city id related places list

My question is i try this but not display city id related places view. It's display all places. 
Here my button click event in city info:

```
Button places = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
places.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Launching place
        String cid_li = ((TextView) arg0.findViewById(R.id.cid_li)).getText().toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PlacesActivity.class);
            // Starting new intent
            i.putExtra(TAG_CID_LI, cid_li);
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        }           
    });
```

and this I using for getting city id related places in places activity code

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        if (cid_li != null) {
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cityid", cid_li));
             }
```

please Help me

sorry about my language

Thank you.!

Comment: Atleast show some more piece of code

Comment: Thanks.Here my code :https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bg1k8vfzc95qdmu/kb3g7WVHp5?m

Comment: Thanks, I got answer for above problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in wrong way.
arg0 in your onClick() method gives you the view that is clicked , you have made it anonymous for button , than how can you cast the same in TextView , because it will give you the reference of button that is clicked.If you want some text from textview reference than you can make it global and than use getText method when button is clicked .You must have to give reference to textview in some method before using it.

Show me your whole code .

Comment: Thanks, I got answer for above problem.

Comment: please, I set relationship place id with city id in mysql database.how can get related city name in places list item (i mean in places list item display image,place name and city name)?

Comment: You have to make query on your database to get row details based on your city id .Use a query with a where clause .

Answer (score -1):

your `places` variable is a `ListView` (i Think). If so Use `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. places not variable of ListView,It's button of place, follow my code : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bg1k8vfzc95qdmu/kb3g7WVHp5?m

Comment: Thanks, I got answer for above problem.